# Cypress.io: How to create a function that helps select different DOM elements based on input

Tags: javascript, cypress

I understand that you cannot assign or work with the return values of any Cypress command, however, I want to be able to write a utility function that allows me to select whichever DOM element I wish without having to explicitly write in a DOM selector each time since my key value is the same for all of my tests.

An example of what I mean is something like this:

```html
<div data-e2e="one-div-element">
<div data-e2e="second-div-element>
<div data-e2e="third-div-element>
<div data-e2e="fourth-div-element>
```

I wish to be able to do the allowed equivalent of:

```
const getByE2EID = (id) => cy.get('[data-e2e="${id}"]') // <--- (this of course, would be interpolated)
```

and then I'd be able to write a test like:

```
getByE2EID('third-div-element') // <--- and then I'd have the third div
```

---

I am trying to AVOID doing:

```
cy.get('[data-e2e="first-div-element"]')
```

For every time I wish to grab a DOM element because it ends up being...

```
cy.get('[data-e2e="first-div-element"]')
cy.get('[data-e2e="second-div-element"]')
cy.get('[data-e2e="third-div-element"]')
cy.get('[data-e2e="fourth-div-element"]')
```

Over and over.

Comment: What do you want to do with the result of your function? Do you want to get the actual DOM node or a normal Cypress object (e.g. like `getByE2EID('third-div-element').contains('foo')`)?

Comment: I would like to get the Cypress object - yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the help everyone! With your suggestions, I was able to translate what I needed to write in Cypress.io to make this idea work and it came down to writing this inside of the `commands.js` file in the support directory:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getDataE2EID', function (id) {
  return cy.get(`[data-e2e="${id}"]`)
})
```

`cy.getDataE2EID('first-div-element')` <--- will get me the first div

Now, I can have a custom cypress function that allows me to pass in whatever value I want where the key is 'data-e2e'.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you use proper [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
const getByE2EID = (id) => cy.get(`[data-e2e="${id}"]`)
```

Note: `` ` `` instead of `'`.

Read "[Return Values](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values)" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with es6 array functions:

```
function getByE2EIDs(...ids) {
  return ids.map(cy.get(`[data-e2e="${id}"]`));
}

getByEIDs(id1, id2, id3, id4);
```

alternatively:

```
function getByE2EIDs(ids) {
  return ids.map(cy.get(`[data-e2e="${id}"]`));
}

getByEIDs([id1, id2, id3, id4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can define the function like:

```
const getByE2EID = ( val )=> document.querySelector(`[data-e2e='${val}']`);
```

And you can use it getByE2EID('fourth-div-element'), But for using this your html should be valid like:

```
<div data-e2e="one-div-element">Div 1</div>
<div data-e2e="second-div-element">Div 2</div>
<div data-e2e="third-div-element">Div 3</div>
<div data-e2e="fourth-div-element">Div 4</div>
```